# Action form_for -> show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

URL :  `/evaluations`

I have made a form to select a specific item (a period)

```
class EvaluationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @periods = Period.all
  end
```

My form :

```
<% form_for XXXXX do %>
  <%= collection_select(:period, :period_id, @periods, :id, :fullname) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Valider") %>
<% end %>
```

I would like the form to go to /evaluations/3 when submited (if the selected period is 3).

When I go manually to /evaluations/3 it works like a charm but I really don't know how to write the form_for to go the right url by submitting the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple way**

Submit period ID to process data, and then redirect to action, which handles 
  `evaluations/:id` with `:id` as parameters.

```
redirect_to <youraction>(:period => @id)
```

This should do the trick.

**Not so simple way**

If you want to change something dynamically on your page after data was submitted - call method and respond with javascript

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js 
end
```

In javascript response you can put whatever you want - simple redirects or script, which will change page dynamically. It's up to you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: great ! that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

you need to use some javascript to update the `action` of the form

```
$('#period_period_id').change(function() {
  $('form').attr('action', '/evaluations/' + this.value);
})
```

Comment: really ? no way to do it in rails ?

Comment: yes.  when the page has already loaded, rails has no way to change the html generated. since you're basing the url of the form on the period_id, you can't expect rails to know it before you render the page.

Comment: yes that's right. and what about the original form tag ? form_for XXXXX do ?

Comment: hmm that's a good question.  if you have a default value for period_id, then use that to set the default action of the form.  if you don't, just use '#'